# Unlimited online backup space for fixed price using rsync/FTP/other simple protocol

Tags: backup, online-storage, mozy

Many companies offer unlimited online backup space for a fixed price 
(mozy.com, twitter.com/allmydata, onlinestoragesolution.com, etc), but 
they either use proprietary non-Linux-friendly software and/or have 
gone out of business and/or don't actually work.

Who offers reliable unlimited online backup space for a fixed price 
that's compatible with rsync, FTP, or other generic/open source file 
transfer protocols?

Or, has anyone written software that lets me treat Mozy's/etc space as 
though it were regular file space (eg, "mozyfs"?)

Comment: since mozy works by backing up various directories on your computer, it can't backup more than your hard drive space. (that's my experience with the free/2gb one anyway).  unlimited is normally a bit gimmicky, 'cos you know how computers work. there are limits. yahoo mail called itself unlimited but every file had to be <=3MB. gmail followed.. currently about 20MB or so.  I doubt you'd get an unlimited space FTP server! how would it work!

Comment: Barlop, I was talking about the $5/month mozy service, which really is unlimited. However, using their backup program is klunky, and it's hard to tell what's been backed up and what hasn't been, plus it doesn't work w/ Linux.

Comment: Can I ask this in web apps? stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this myself, and found a small-business that offered this. The only problem was that the support seemed non-existent (like most services in my honest opinion).
The service was http://www.onlinestoragesolution.com/

It seemed to work and they have a lot of the popular protocols setup....however, my fear was that they seemed shady enough to disappear tomorrow - along with my data. Something in the back of my head has lead me to question those who advertise unlimited anything. There is nothing in their TOS to suggest foul play. It could just be the voices in my head though, they are always on high alert.

Comment: Actually, I think mention that one above. I tried them, paid the $21 for one year's worth of service, and it worked fine at first. When it broke, it took the admin 2 months to finally fix the problem. After it broke again, I haven't been able to contact the admin at all. If anyone else has good experience w/ them, maybe I just haven't pushed for a fix hard enough.